# "В другом случае" - общее ли для данного ССП?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

> В другом случае в центральном круге могла присутствовать Дева Мария(,) и
>   тогда её окружали Силы Небесные, согласно их небесной иерархии –
>   херувимы, серафимы, ангелы, архангелы.

То есть вопрос о запятой: ставить - не ставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Тогда" связывает первое предложение со вторым. "В другом случае" не может относиться ко второму предложению, "в другом случае тогда" — лишено смысла.
Запятая нужна.